# How can I select the first child of all the children of a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a `<tr>` which includes several `<td>`s, each of which includes exactly one `<div>`, which may have further structure:

```
<tr id="foo">
  <td><div>...</div></td>
  <td><div>...</div></td>
  ...
  <td><div>...</div></td>
</tr>
```

Given a jQuery selector `obj = $('#foo')`, how can I get a selector that points to all the `<div>`s directly under a `<td>` directly under the `<tr>` (but nothing within the `<div>`s)? In other words, how can I compose a selector equivalent to:

```
$('#foo > td > div')
```

using `obj` (defined as `$('#foo')`) in the form `obj.someFunction()`?

Probably `chldren()` and/or `find()` may be relevant, but I am not sure.

Comment: `obj.find('td div')` would be explicit....  really not clear what you want to do with them. `obj.find('td:has(div)')` will give you the TD's in question,  might be what you want

Comment: @charlietfl I guess you meant `obj.find('td > div')`. Does that select `td div` anywhere below `'#foo'` (i.e., equivalent to `$('#foo td > div')`) or only the objects directly below `'#foo'` (i.e., equivalent to `$('#foo > td > div')`)?

Comment: I'm still not clear what you are really trying to target. Adding `>` will provide only children `$('#foo > td ')` wouldn't work I don't think...no td children of foo   http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you only want the first child, or do you want all of them?

Comment: As I wrote, each `<td>` has exactly one `<div>`, so all children of them is the same as the first child of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always call `.children()` twice:

```
obj.children('td').children('div')
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be it.

Comment: In terms of performance, how do you think about `obj.children('td > div')` (given by Matej Chrenko) compared to `obj.children('td').children('div')`?

Comment: @sawa: You cannot compare them by performance because they work differently. `obj.children('td > div')` means "find the children of `obj` that are `td > div`". Since the immediate descendants of `obj` are `td`, not `div`, that won't match anything. There's also `obj.find('td > div')` instead, but that might look in other `td`s as well. I *think* you can use `obj.find('> td > div')` (notice the extra `>`), but in any case when it comes to performance the best answer lies in benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

obj.find('td > div'); same as $('#foo td > div');

obj.children('td > div'); same as $('#foo > td > div');

Comment: you want to select div inside #foo td but nothing inside this div

Comment: Is this equivalent to `$('#foo td > div')` or `$('#foo > td > div')`?

Comment: Then that is not what I want.

Comment: Do you have another table in td elements? If not nothing`s change.

Comment: @sawa I think this is what you want...but still not 100% clear what you are trying to do

Comment: you can also use obj.children('td > div'); it is the same as $('#foo > td > div')

Comment: That is what I wanted. In terms of performance, how do you think about `obj.children('td > div')` compared to `obj.children('td').children('div')` (given by BoltClock)?

Comment: This turned out not to be what I wanted. See BoltClock's answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this in jQuery:

```
$("#foo td > div:first-child")
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EHZK8/

This will select the first child div, even if there is more than one child div and it will avoid sub-children divs too.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This works and is more tolerant of variations in the HTML struture than even the best answer.  So, why downvote?